# Call WordPress plugin variable in theme file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to call a WordPress plugin variable value in my theme file and echo it there but i doesn't do it. Here is what i tried.

The plugin variable is

```
$thumbs-rating;
```

I just did normal echo in the theme file like this

```
<div><?php echo $thumbs-rating ?></div>
```

I read somewhere that i need to set the variable as global. So, i tried

```
global $thumbs-rating;
```

but did not work.

Comment: add `global` in the plugin file, where variable defined and in the place, where you want to call it. Another way use `filter` to access your variable

Comment: i tried global it didnt work. Could you pleqse explqin how to use filter to access the variable?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using class structure in your plugin than you should create function in plugin to get variable of that file

-- its standard way to get, set and use variable of plugin(class) at any where in theme

for example

> in plugin file

```
class MY_Class {
    /** @var float Cart grand total. */
    public $total;
    /**
     * Get total.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_total() {
        return $this->total;
    }
    public function set_total($total) {
        $this->total = $total;
    }
}
```

> in function file

```
$my_class = new MY_Class;
$total = $my_class->get_total();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions to use `variable` defined in the plugin into theme files.

As we know, plugins loads earlier than themes. So, we could without any problem defined some variable in the plugin, and then use it in theme:

**Plugin file:**

```
global $my_var;
$my_var= 'something';
```

**Theme file:**

```
global $my_var;
echo $my_var;
```

---

Take a note, that when you use `global` in the function, then you should to `hook` function somwhere. It's mean that possible to not get that `global` variable directly in the theme file, because it may not been defined( called function ) yet.

Getting access to `global` defined in the plugin function directly in theme file:

**Plugin file:**

```
function ww_new(){
    global $ww_new;

    $ww_new = 'something';
}
add_action('wp_roles_init', 'ww_new');
```

**Theme file:**

```
global $ww_new;
echo $ww_new;
```

We used `wp_roles_init` hook, which fired before theme setup. It's mean, that we can access the global without any problem. But if we use some other hook, like `init`, then our `global` will be empty.

---

Just accessing to some variable using function and [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/):

**Plugin file:**

```
function ww_new()
{
    $ww_var['a'] = 99;
    $ww_var['b'] = 999;

    $ww_var = apply_filters('ww_filter', $ww_var);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'ww_new');
```

**Theme file:**

```
function ww_func($var){
    var_dump($var);
    //your code

    return $var;
}
add_filter('ww_filter', 'ww_func', 10, 1);
```

We used `after_setup_theme` hook to have access to our variable and can use filter in the theme files. There are just several default `hooks`, which fires before theme activating and using which we can't access to our variable.

Answer (score 0):

seems you forgot ">" ! `$thumbs-rating;` wrong, change your code like this:

```
global $thumbs;
echo $thumbs->rating; // or if rating is a function: echo $thumbs->rating();
```

Comment: Sorry i put that $thumbs-rating; just as an example i know that variable can not have dash in a variable name. let say my variabel is $thumbs_rating

Comment: What do you mean? the plugin is activated and functions fine, but it has a variable that i want to print somewhere else